# @RunAs for @WebService EJB

Tags: java, web-services, security, ejb

I have an anonymous WebService EJB - webservice calls are working poperly.

Now I want the WebService to RunAs as a specific SecurityRole.

At the Webservice I have following Annotations:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
@DeclareRoles({ "LoggedUser" })
@SecurityDomain("my-jboss-real")
@RunAs("LoggedUser")
public class MyWebService { ...
```

Now I want to access a `@EJB` with `@RolesAllowed({"LoggedUser"})` from an Webservice Method there I get:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException.message: 'Caller unauthorized'
WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessBeanContext] EJBTHREE-1337: do not get WebServiceContext property from stateless bean context, it should already have been injected
ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException.message: 'Caller unauthorized'
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:115)
```

I'm running on JBoss 5.1GA

Is this the right use of `@RunAs` or is there another way to do this.

**Edit**

Added:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsCtx;
@Resource
private EJBContext ejbCtx;

myWebServiceMethod(){
     ...
     System.out.println("EJBCtx: " + ejbCtx.getCallerPrincipal());
     System.out.println("EJBCtx: " + ejbCtx.isCallerInRole("LoggedUser"));
     System.out.println("WebContext: " + wsCtx.getUserPrincipal());
     System.out.println("WebContext: " + wsCtx.isUserInRole("LoggedUser"));
     ...
```

This Outputs:

```
EJBCtx: anonymous
EJBCtx: false
WebContext: anonymous
WebContext: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss AS 5 and especially 6 are very buggy with regard to a security context and @RunAs in anything but the most basic usecases.

A large number of those bugs have been fixed in
AS 7. You could try to setup a test case there and see if you run into the same issue.

Do realize that @RunAs does not apply to the code that runs in the bean on which the annotation is applied. Instead, it only applies to beans that are called -from- that bean. You could think of it as the "outgoing/outbound" role.

More troublesome is that Java EE has a serious ommission and that's that there is no way to also define a RunAs *identity*. Some servers don't react well when you define a RunAs role for the "unauthenticated" identity. JBoss has a proprietary annotation for the RunAs identify. You might want to try if this takes you a step further.